# Texture rendering on iOS using OpenGL ES in Unity project

Tags: ios, opengl-es, ffmpeg, rgb, yuv

I'm working on a project, part of which is to stream video to my iPhone. I use my laptop to create the video stream to my iPhone with ffmpeg.

The stream code in shell is below:

```
ffmpeg \
    -f avfoundation -i "1" -s 1280*720 -r 29.97 \
    -c:v mpeg2video -q:v 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 1 -threads 4\
    -f mpegts udp://192.168.1.102:6666
```

with this, I successfully create my video stream.

In Unity, I want to decode the video stream to create a texture. After I have gone through some ffmpeg tutorial and Unity tutorial, I created my link library. Some of these codes are below (ask me if more is needed):

**In my library:**

buffer alloc:

```
uint8_t *buffer;
int buffer_size;
buffer_size = avpicture_get_size(AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA, VIEW_WIDTH, VIEW_HEIGHT);

buffer = (uint8_t *) av_malloc(buffer_size*sizeof(uint8_t));

avpicture_fill((AVPicture *) pFrameRGB, buffer, AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA,
               VIEW_WIDTH, VIEW_HEIGHT);
```

getContext:

```
    is->sws_ctx = sws_getContext
    (
     is->video_st->codec->width,
     is->video_st->codec->height,
     is->video_st->codec->pix_fmt,
     VIEW_WIDTH,
     VIEW_HEIGHT,
     AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA,
     SWS_BILINEAR,
     NULL,
     NULL,
     NULL
     );
```

sws_scale:

```
sws_scale(
          is->sws_ctx,
          (uint8_t const * const *)pFrame->data,
          pFrame->linesize,
          0,
          is->video_st->codec->height,
          pFrameRGB->data,
          pFrameRGB->linesize
          );
```

texture render:

```
static void UNITY_INTERFACE_API OnRenderEvent(int texID)
{
    GLuint gltex = (GLuint)(size_t)(texID);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gltex);

    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, VIEW_WIDTH, VIEW_HEIGHT,
                    GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pFrameRGB->data[0]);

    glGetError();
    return;
}

extern "C" UnityRenderingEvent UNITY_INTERFACE_EXPORT UNITY_INTERFACE_API GetRenderEventFunc()
{
    return OnRenderEvent;
}
```

**In Unity:**

texture created:

```
    private Texture2D texture;
    private int texID;
    texture = new Texture2D (width, height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
    texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
    texture.Apply ();
    GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.mainTexture = texture;
    texID = texture.GetNativeTexturePtr ().ToInt32();
```

update func:

```
    void Update ()
    {
        GL.IssuePluginEvent(GetRenderEventFunc(), texID);
    }
```

**Video stream info:**

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://0.0.0.0:6666':
  Duration: N/A, start: 2.534467, bitrate: N/A
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], max. 104857 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
```

Leave other details, my library works fine on the Unity simulator, but when I compiled all my libraries for arm64 and used the xcode project that Unity created to build my app and ran it, I couldn't get any texture rendered in my iPhone, I checked my network and I'm sure that data had been sent to my iPhone and the Debug log showed me that frame has been successfully decoded also the `OnRenderEvent` function had been called.

**FYI:**

Unity 5.3.2f1 Personal

Xcode 7.2.1

iOS   9.2.1

ffmpeg 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,I figured it out myself.

It turns out that Graphics APIs for iOS 9 in Unity 5.3.2f1 is `Auto Graphics API` by default and it will be `Metal`.Therefore,in my app I can't use `OpenGL ES` API to manipulate my frame.

After I set `Graphics API` to `OpenGL ES 3`,It all goes well.